# how to use ser2net control port

Tags: proxy, utilities, serial-port, serial-console

`man ser2net` says that by running `ser2net` with a `-p` flag I can execute a number of commands.  If I run `ser2net -p 12345` and, then, `lsof -i :12345`, I can see the service on that port.  How would I, for example, send the command `showport` to ser2net?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ser2net control port is mapped to TCP port 12345 on the device running ser2net.  Open a telnet session to that port from another device on the network that can see it.  Assuming that the IP of your device is 192.168.0.2, something like this would work:

```
telnet 192.168.0.2 12345
->
-> showport
TCP Port 4000
  enable state: telnet
  timeout: 0
[etc...]
```